# iFrame did not Displayed

Tags: java, iframe, webdriver

Could someone help me to solve following:
Have an iframe and found it by xPath correctly.

```
div[@id='sidebar']/div[@class='banner-300-250']//iframe
```

Here is source code:

```
<div class="banner-300-250">
<script type="text/javascript">if(!window.AdButler){(function(){var   s=document.createElement("script");s.async=true;s.type="text/javascript";  s.src='https://servedbyadbutler.com/app.js';var   n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(s,n);}());}</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">var AdButler=AdButler||{};   AdButler.ads=AdButler.ads||[];var abkw=window.abkw||'';var plc177931=window.plc177931||0;document.write('<'+'div id="placement_177931_'+plc177931+'"></'+'div>'); AdButler.ads.push({handler:function(opt){AdButler.register(166212,177931,[300,250],'placement_177931_'+opt.place,opt);},opt:{place:plc177931++,keywords:abkw,domain:'servedbyadbutler.com'}});</script>     <script async="" type="text/javascript" src="https://servedbyadbutler.com/adserve/;ID=166212;size=300x250;setID=177931;type=async;domid=placement_177931_0;place=0;pid=894989;sw=1920;sh=1080;spr=1;rnd=894989;kw=sport"></script><div id="placement_177931_0"><iframe id="placement_177931_0_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="250" width="300"></iframe></div>
</div>
<iframe id="placement_177931_0_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="250" width="300"></iframe>
.
.
.
<a href="//wlpinnaclesports.adsrv.eacdn.com/C.ashx?btag=a_773b_3429c_&amp;affid=4609&amp;siteid=773&amp;adid=3429&amp;c=&amp;MediaID=3429&amp;IsAd=1&amp;     <script src="//pinnaclesports.host.bannerflow.com/bf_ph_642.js?btag=a_773b_3429" charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"> </script>            
        </a>
```

Tried with this code, and its works when iframe is shown, but on some pages it does not exist, and in that case I am getting broken test (did not add simple for loop in below code, but it is written and therefore is counter (i) in code below:

```
List<WebElement> bookieBanners = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='sidebar']/div[@class='banner-300-250']"));
    System.out.println(bookieBanners.);
    if (bookieBanners.get(i).isDisplayed()) {
        System.out.println(bookieBanners);
        bookieBanners.get(i).click();
        BaseTest.sleepSeconds(2);
        switchToLastOpenedWindow(driver);
        System.out.println("Opened is page: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        BaseTest.closePrevWindows(driver);
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no banner for bookies");
        continue;
      }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggling, solution is as follows:

```
List<WebElement> subMenuElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(Found Elements));
    if (subMenuElements.size() > 0) {
        for (int p = 0; p < subMenuElements.size(); p++) {
            if (p < 9) {
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("******");
                //Open in another tab that page
                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('a').attr('target', '_blank');");
                subMenuElements.get(p).click();
                BaseTest.sleepSeconds(3);
                System.out.println("Checking banner on " + subMenuElements.get(p).getText());
                System.out.println("Checking banner on " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
                List<WebElement> bookieLinks = driver.findElements(By.xpath("Found inner iframe"));
                System.out.println("Second banner:");
                System.out.println("*****");
                if ((bookieLinks.size() > 0)) {
                    WebElement bookieShown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Banner is clickable at position 'banner-300-250']"));
                    bookieShown.click();
                    switchToLastOpenedWindow(driver);
                    BaseTest.sleepSeconds(3);
                    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
                    System.out.println("Page title: " + driver.getTitle());
                    BaseTest.closePrevWindows(driver);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Banner not shown on current page");
                    BaseTest.closePrevWindows(driver);
                }
```